# EmberJS - Minimal dependencies loading

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an EmberJS single page frontend app. I want to split resources(js/html) loaded for different pages. Right now, ember builds the hole javascript code into a single file which then is included in the DOM. The same with the templates.

What I want is to load a small piece of template/js for some specify routes, because I need them to be fast. When the user moves to a new route, I can download the hole one-page app, but for these routes I need the minimum resources loaded.

How can I achieve this using emberjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there's no way to do that using EmberJS. 
Ember-CLI will build your project into the `app-name.js`file (will all your routes/templates/components) and the `vendor.js` file which contains all the files you included in your `ember-cli-build.js` using `app.import()`.

I've seen people ask this, but I never seen a reply which included a way to do this.